# Word using Excel database

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have a similar spreadsheet. I insert the database into word and use the columns

```
ID   Name       Attachment    email

id1  firstname test1.pdf   test@test.com

id1  firstname test1.pdf   test@test.com

id1  firstname test1.pdf   test@test.com

id2  firstname test2.pdf   test2@test.com
```

when I send out the emails in word, I would like to **merge same id attachments to one email**, instead of sending 3 emails.

Is there any way to do it in word. I use mail merge word plugin.